# JQuery animate always removes display:none and adds display:block to inline css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running some simple jquery for animation over a group of images. Some of the images are hidden and some are not. But it seems jquery is just making them all visible, I want to animate these with changing how they display.

```
$('.productImageLarge').animate({
    width: 185,
    height: 185
});
```

JQuery automatically makes them all display:block.

Is it possible to animate without changing the display visibility.

Thanks

Comment: Add HTML markup into question.

Comment: When you asked to animate something, jQuery assumes that you want to make it visible.  Why are you calling animate on things that are not visible.  It may be easier to just not call animate() on things that are not visible.  You can use `$('.productImageLarge:visible').animate()` to select only the visible items.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the specify the display property and add a !important declaration jQuery will restore the display property after it completes its animation. For example, if you run this command on the jQuery homepage it will set the first book image to display:inline, animate it and then validate that the resulting HTML has the correct display property.

```
$($(".jq-bookImg").get(0))
    .css("display","inline !important")
    .animate({ width: 85, height: 185 }, function(){
        console.log("display propery is " + $(this).css("display"));
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. How does this work with show, hide, fadeIn? In the context that I want to use show and hide on my images and then animate, keep the same, then use show and hide again?

Comment: With hide and fadeOut you don't want to have a display property with the !important declaration or it will trump jQuery's setting of it to none. As far as show and fadeIn the same principal applies, just set the display to `inline !important` like I demonstrated above.

Comment: this is one of those fixes that makes you have faith in the world. Thanks!